# What do these htaccess directives mean?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can you help me to understand this `.htaccess` code?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I don't understand if is correct, but if I write my website url nothing happens....blank page.
thank you

If you want I can add other informations

Comment: "If you want I can add other informations" - yes, please! As it stands, there is no question here. Whether those directives are "correct" or not depends entirely on what you are trying to do. Those directives are not necessarily "wrong". (Although the 2nd to last rule is a little odd and misplaced.) What are you trying to do exactly? What requests are you making? How are you expecting these requests to be handled? (Where did you get these rules from?) etc.

Answer (score 1):

In short, these directives internally rewrite all requests that do not map to physical files or directories or that end in `.php` (whether they exist as files or not) to `/index.php` in the document root.

There's nothing actually "wrong" with these directives. But whether they are "correct" depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

It is a "standard" front-controller pattern.

However, there is one thing... these directives are dependent on `DirectoryIndex index.php` being set in a parent config. This would normally be set in the main server config, although the Apache *default* (if this directive is not explicitly set) is `index.html`, not `index.php`. If this is not set to `index.php` then `/index.php` would not be called when requesting the document root. Although in this case you would expect a 403 Forbidden response, not a "blank page".

A "blank page" more likely suggests an error in your applciation.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
> ```

This rule prevents any request that ends in `.php` from being rewritten/routed to `/index.php`. I said in comments that this is a little "misplaced", because if you are going to do something like this it would be far more efficient/simpler to combine it with the first rule and avoid the unnecessary filesystem checks.

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

As it stands, the `RewriteBase` directive is not actually required.

But to clarify, this change makes no difference to the outcome of these directives (apart from maybe the addition of the `DirectoryIndex` directive). It just makes it more efficient/tidy.